# Applying Angular Filter with hierarchical json object from controller js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to Angualar js and json and frontend dev.so pls forgive my ignorance.I wanted to filter a json object based on a property:value. 
it doesn't contain arrays. and the property:value is always at the second level.its a hierarchical json not an array(parent->children->again children.).
I have seen variants of the same question but most of them are dealing with array.
below is my sample json.

```
            {
         "key1":
         {
         "prop11": "value11",
         "prop2" : "N",
         "prop13" : "value13" 
         },
         "key2":
         {
         "prop21": "value21",
         "prop2" : "Y",
         "prop33" : "value23" 
         },
          "key3":
         {
         "prop31": "value11", 
         "prop33" : "value13",
         "prop2" : "N",
         },
         "key4":
         {
         "prop41": "value21",
         "prop2" : "Y",
         "prop43" : "value23" 
         },
         .
         .
         .
         .

        }
```

I want to filter all children into a json object based on the value of prop2.
that is, if prop2 : 'Y', then I want to add it to my final object.

Is this posible using angular js filter.
I tried below sample but couldn't get desired results.

```
$filter('filter')(JSON.parse(jsonString),JSON.parse("{ \"Mandatory\":\"Y\"}"))

or
$filter('filter')(JSON.parse(jsonString),JSON.parse("{$:{Mandatory:'y'}}"))
```

or i tried to covert the sample json string to an array with single object by adding square bracket.

```
var array = '[ '+ jsonString + ' ]';
$filter('filter')(array,{$:{Mandatory:'y'}});
```

None of this worked.I am using the filter from the controller js file.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom filter to help you achieve what you want:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(data) {
    newObj = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
      if(v.prop2 === 'Y') {
        newObj.push(v);
      }
    });
    return newObj;
  }
});
```

Here is the implementation, I'm just assigning your data to a variable on the `$scope` then displaying the data and applying the filter by doing `{{data | myFilter}}`.

You can run the code snippet to see it in action.

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  
  $scope.data = {
    "key1": {
      "prop11": "value11",
      "prop2": "N",
      "prop13": "value13"
    },
    "key2": {
      "prop21": "value21",
      "prop2": "Y",
      "prop33": "value23"
    },
    "key3": {
      "prop31": "value11",
      "prop33": "value13",
      "prop2": "N",
    },
    "key4": {
      "prop41": "value21",
      "prop2": "Y",
      "prop43": "value23"
    }
  }
  
  
}]);
  
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(data) {
    newObj = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
      if(v.prop2 === 'Y') {
        newObj.push(v);
      }
    });
    return newObj;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngApp">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>maxisam's ngApp</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  {{data | myFilter}}
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

hope it helps

Comment: Getting an error running this: 
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 33,
  "colno": 19
}